# Как добавить файлы из папки в удаленный репозиторий github не включая саму папку?

Tags: git, gitlab

В проекте есть папка dist с вложенными файлами и папками проекта. Как добавить в удаленный репозиторий github эти файлы и папки без самой папки dist, в которой они находятс ?

Comment: Сделать локальный репозиторий в папке dist и синхронизировать его.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask добро пожаловать на сайт !!! S Wave, полезная ссылка, как задать качественный вопрос на данном ресурсе.